# JMeter: Holding Session for a certain period of time

Tags: session, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

Is it possible to hold a session for a certain period of time using JMeter? While using "Ultimate Thread Group"
Ultimate Thread Group: 100 users will be ramping up  and run for 15 minutes. Then another set of 100 user will be ramping up after 15 minutes and it will continue till it reaches 1000 users. No iteration and Total sample count should be 1000. Application session time out is 15 minutes. Logout transaction should execute once all 1000 users are reached.
Attached the load profile:
[Load Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVz5D.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Total sample count should be 1000

this is not something that you can get for sure because the total number of requests you will be able to make using the above setup will depend mostly on :

- **your application response time**
- the nature of your test (i.e. think times)

You can use i.e. a [Dummy Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/DummySampler/) where you can mimic various connect time, latency and response time and see what will be the number of requests you will make in 2.5 hours, however my expectation is that 1000 concurrent users will be able to conduct much more than 1000 requests given the test duration.

More information: [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second/)

If you want to introduce a "hard limit" on the number of requests you can consider adding [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in `Total Executions` mode.